# Replacing NA in longitudinal data with average difference of non-missing values

Tags: r, missing-data

Here is a simplified version of the data I am working with:

```html
data.frame(country = c("country1", "country2", "country3", "country1", "country2"), measurement = c("m1", "m1", "m1", "m2", "m2"), 
y2015 = c(NA, 15, 19, 13, 55), y2016 = c(NA, 17, NA, 10, NA), y2017 = c(14, NA, NA, 9, 45), y2018 = c(18, 22, 16, NA, 40))
```

I am trying to take the difference between the two non-missing variables on either side of the NAs, and replace the missing values with the average of the differences over time.

For row 5, this would be something like c(55, *50*, 45, *40*).

However, it also needs to work for the rows that have more than one missing value in a sequence, like row 1 and row 3. For row 1, I'd like the difference between 14 and 18 to be interpolated, and so it should look something like c(*6*, *10*, 14, 18). Meanwhile, for row 3, the difference between 19-13 divided between the two missing years, to look something like c(19, *18*, *17*, 16).

Essentially, I'm looking to create a slope for each country and measurement through the available years, and interpolating missing variables based on that.

I am trying to think of a package for this or perhaps create a loop. I have looked at the package 'spline' but does not seem to work since I want to run separate linear interpolation based on country and measurement.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably include the expected output for all rows. Right now you don't mention how you would want to deal with rows 2 and 4, which happen to be the interesting cases. Also, imputing values outside the observed range is really _extrapolation_, not interpolation. The distinction is important because for example for linear extrapolation you'll need a method to decide what slope to use, whereas for interpolation you just "connect the dots."

Answer (score 0):

Use `zoo::na.spline`:

```r
library(zoo)
dat[-c(1:2)] <- t(na.spline(t(dat[-c(1:2)])))

   country measurement y2015 y2016    y2017 y2018
1 country1          m1     6    10 14.00000    18
2 country2          m1    15    17 19.33333    22
3 country3          m1    19    18 17.00000    16
4 country1          m2    13    10  9.00000    10
5 country2          m2    55    50 45.00000    40
```

Comment: `na.spline` can handle multiple columns so we don't need `apply.`  Try `ok <- sapply(dat, is.numeric);  replace(dat, ok, t(na.spline(t(dat[ok]))))` or use `na.approx` to get linear interpoloation.  See `?na.approx` and `?na.spline` for addition arguments and info.